# Angular 2 - Typescript choking on object dot notation, expects ';'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm new to TypeScript and Angular 2. I am in the process of moving a project over from Angular 1 and I'm having trouble getting some of my property definitions into the Angular 2 component.

I have these property definitions:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'contact-detail',
  templateUrl: 'app/contacts/contact-detail.template.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/contacts/contact-detail.style.css']
})
export class ContactDetailComponent {
  contactFormOptions = {};
  contactFormOptions.initDateDefault = '';
  contactFormOptions.followUpDateDefault = '';
  contactBasicInfo: {};
  contactBasicInfo.bdMonth = '0';
  contactBasicInfo.bdDay = '0';
}
```

Angular 1 was fine with me defining object properties (like `contactFormOptions.initDateDefault = '';`) this way. With the dot syntax. However, Typescript chokes on the dot notation of those properties and says a `;` is expected. Why? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess those properties are not defined. You should use the brackets notation

Comment: Chokes on this, too: `contactFormOptions['initDateDefault'] = moment();` Says it expects `=`. I am trying to define the properties in those lines for later use.

Comment: Can you give more context on where this code is run? :)

Comment: Okay, I added the entire component. I did take out the methods and things that had no bearing on defining these properties, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it's just me being new to the OOP world. What I needed to do was declare the properties and their types and then assign values within a constructor (or method).

```
export class ContactDetailComponent {
  contactFormOptions: any = {};
  contactBasicInfo: any = {};

  constructor ( ) {
    this.contactFormOptions.initDateDefault = moment();
    this.contactFormOptions.followUpDateDefault = moment().add(7, 'days');
    this.contactBasicInfo.bdMonth = '0';
    this.contactBasicInfo.bdDay = '0';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript to understand `moment.js` you need a definition file. Luckily, one is provided with `moment.js` and you only need to add the reference, which has also been figured out here, at Defintely Typed:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment/moment.d.ts

For clarity, what need to be added to the code is:

`declare var moment: moment.MomentStatic;`

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with moment. It'll do the same thing even if I'm just trying to set the value to an empty string (not using moment at all).

Comment: Updated my question to remove moment.js from the equation. It still chokes on the dot notation of object properties.